# Response Status HTTP SpringBoot Kotlin Api

Tags: api, spring-boot, kotlin, microservices

I'm starting in kotlin and if anyone can help me, I've had a question about how I can return the http status, when my true if it returns 200 Ok and when it's any other way, return 404 NotFound.

I tried to do according to the code below, but it is only returning status 200 Ok, in all situations

```
@DeleteMapping("{id}")
fun delete(@PathVariable id: Long): ResponseEntity<Unit> {
    try {
        if (dogRepository.exists(id)) {
            dogRepository.delete(id)
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think an else block can do that

```
 @DeleteMapping("{id}") fun delete(@PathVariable id: Long): ResponseEntity<Unit> { 
   try {
             if (dogRepository.exists(id)) { 
                dogRepository.delete(id)
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
            } 
    } catch (e: Exception) { return ResponseEntity.notFound().build() }
 }
```

Comment: Glad it helped you. Would you consider upvote if this solved your problem?

Comment: yes, but I do not have enough score yet to up, my account is new

Comment: @DesenvolvimentoOphos No issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are not throwing an exception anywhere, hence catch block is not getting executed. Here is updated code.

```
    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    fun delete(@PathVariable id: Long): ResponseEntity {
        try {
            if (dogRepository.exists(id)) {
                dogRepository.delete(id)
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build()
            }
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
        }
    }
```

You can check the response header via curl . E.g.
`curl -v -X  DELETE http://YOUR_API_URL`

Comment: In this case, throwing an exception only to catch it again does not make sense. It would be better to return not found from an else branch, and remove the try/catch.

Comment: @PeterHart, fully agree, thought that OP posted the minimal code thats why didn't mentioned it. Updated my code